# Unable to start service nexus on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run Nexus on Ubuntu 22.04 EC2 instance of type t2.micro

I have followed this article to do so

https://www.fosstechnix.com/how-to-install-nexus-repository-on-ubuntu/

However when i run the command

```
sudo systemctl status nexus
```

I get below

```
sudo systemctl status nexus
× nexus.service - nexus service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nexus.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-07-14 21:59:23 UTC; 6s ago
    Process: 8096 ExecStart=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8269 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 160ms
```

Also I have tried to check the logs by running

```
tail -f /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/nexus.log
```

And I get

```
tail: cannot open '/opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/nexus.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

This is the `nexus.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=nexus service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
LimitNOFILE=65536
ExecStart=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus start
ExecStop=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus stop
User=nexus
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any idea why it's failing?

Comment: It's not a systemd issue.  The process is starting fine, but it exits with code 1.  This is a `nexus`-specific issue.  And those instructions you linked seem a little weird as it seems to ask you to manually patch a lot of stuff.

Comment: Why do you follow a guide like that instead of the official installation instructions? https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation-and-upgrades